# Accessing only the Text but not the html tags from the API data

Tags: reactjs, api

Here is the screenshot of the data fetched from the API.[screenshot of data fetched from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20v9s.png)
The property "summary" has text wrapped in

and  tag with "".
Here is the API I am using [Link to the API](https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all)

While rendering summary I want to display only the text part and not the html tags

and 
Here is my code

```
const Home = () => {
    const [movies, setMovies] =useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData =async()=>{  
    try{
        const  {data} = await axios.get("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all")
        setMovies(data)
        console.log(data)
    }
    catch{

    }
  }
    fetchData()

  
      
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="movieCards-container ">


      <h1 className="heading"> Recommended Movies</h1>
      <div className=" container-custom d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center pb-5 ">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
        {movies.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            <div className=" col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center ">
            <MovieCard 
            key={item.show.id}
            id={item.show.id} 
            name={item.show.name} 
            image={item.show.image.original}
            summary={item.show.summary}
            showday={item.show.schedule.days}
            showtime={item.show.schedule.time}
            
            />
            
      </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove all HTML tags from the rich text?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function for removing tag from text before sending as props

```
function removeTags(str) {
    if ((str===null) || (str===''))
        return false;
    else
        str = str.toString();
          
    // Regular expression to identify HTML tags in
    // the input string. Replacing the identified
    // HTML tag with a null string.
    return str.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');

}



console.log(removeTags("<p>When a rising high school football player from South Central L.A. is recruited to play for Beverly Hills High, the wins, losses and struggles of two families from vastly different worlds — Compton and Beverly Hills — begin to collide. Inspired by the life of pro football player Spencer Paysinger.</p>"));;
```

**My output is** When a rising high school football player from South Central L.A. is recruited to play for Beverly Hills High, the wins, losses and struggles of two families from vastly different worlds — Compton and Beverly Hills — begin to collide. Inspired by the life of pro football player Spencer Paysinger.

Comment: How can I incorporate the custom function in the props?

Comment: What you can do is use this custom function in your movieCard component .There before rendering you can do manipulation of the string